# How to imitate a loop statement in math?

Tags: notation, recursion, programming

I need to iterate through expression several times and quit iteration process when certain value is reached but use algebraic notation. Summation notation would have worked if it didn't sum the expression and if we could quit the process when $i$ reaches certain value.

The concept is this:
$$
i=0\\
\text{START ITERATION PROCESS WITH}\kern{3pt}i:\\
i=i+1\\
\text{IF}\kern{3pt}i\kern{3pt}=5\kern{3pt}\text{, STOP (CONTINUE OTHERWISE)}
$$

How do you do something like this in math?

---

EDIT (additional information): I wouldn't know the value of $i$ in advance and that's what complicates the issue, I would only know the value after expression is finished in each iteration of the process.

Comment: In math writing, we generally do not re-set variables.  If $i=0$ at the beginning of the process, then $i=0$ forever.  Instead, you can use sequence notation: define $x_0$ to be such-and-such, and then explain how to define $x_i$ where $i$ is a dummy variable.

Comment: @JairTaylor, thank you. May I ask you for an example?

Comment: Sure, for example, the Fibonacci sequence: We define $f_1 = f_2 = 1$; and assuming $f_i$ has been computed for $1 \leq i \leq n$, we define $f_{n+1} = f_n + f_{n-1}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor, and how do you stop at, say, $f_{5}$?

Comment: Just say "for $n \leq 5$, define $f_{n} = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$" or something like that.

Comment: @bp2017 You don't necessarily *need* to. Even if you don't stop, you can still talk about $f_5$. $f_5$ is still a thing even after you've defined $f_6$, and $f_10$, and $f_500$. There is no "updating" going on, just new variables.

Answer (score 5):

> For $i$ iterating over the set $\{0,1,2,3, 4\}$, do a thing ...

Math is not a programming language. You don't have to worry about syntax errors. Just use words and letters and numbers to communicate what you want to communicate.

Answer (score 3):

Most mathematics books typically do this using a lot of natural language. For your case, you might say:

---

Suppose $i_{n+1}=i_n+1$ and $i_0=0$. Let us iterate over $n$ until $i_n=5$ (...).